# Why am I not getting a result? Can you please help me take a look?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why am I not getting a result? Can you please help me take a look? I really appreciate it.

[image: my question picture]

```
f (x) = (( Subscript[eD, s] - Subscript[[CurlyEpsilon][Tau], s])/((e^2 + M[CurlyEpsilon]) [Pi]))[ ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (b^2 - x^2)/(b (a - x))] - ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (-b^2 + x^2)/(b (a + x))]] 
Simplify[Integrate[f (x), {x, x, -b}]]
```

Comment: Mathematica functions uses `[ ]` and not `( )`.  Is `e` supposed to be the Euler function or just your own symbol?

Comment: Please post the Mathematica  code.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Your integration limits use the variable `x`? Please improve the quality of your question and also post code. Thanks.

Comment: f (x) = ((
  Subscript[eD, s] - Subscript[\[CurlyEpsilon]\[Tau], 
   s])/((e^2 + M\[CurlyEpsilon]) \[Pi]))[
  ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (b^2 - x^2)/(b (a - x))] - 
   ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (-b^2 + x^2)/(b (a + x))]]
Simplify[Integrate[f (x), {x, x, -b}]]this is my code

Comment: your integration variable is $x$ and the lower limit is $x$? This is little strange.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your limit. You are using upper limit `b` and there is `b` in the integrand. Because of how the anti-derivative came out, there are problems when the upper limit is `b`. Using different letter, say `r` then it can do it. When using `b` for upper limit, Mathematica is having hard time due to singularities.

You can see this as follows. (btw, fixed few problems, you can't use [] for grouping terms, need to use `()` for that). I also removed all those fancy subscripts from your code so I can read it. And you did not answer my question if `e` is meant to be `E`, so I left it as `e`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f = ((eDs - ets)/((e^2 + Me) Pi)) (ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (b^2 - x^2)/(b (a - x))] - 
    ArcCosh[-(x/b) + (-b^2 + x^2)/(b (a + x))])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
anti=Integrate[f ,{x,0,r},GenerateConditions->False,Assumptions->r>0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice what happens if the upper limit $r$ was $b$ instead as you had it. There are terms that look like $b-r$ in the the above sitting down stairs which will cause problems. So  now

```
Limit[anti, r -> b]
```

And Mathematica having hard time with it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So bottom line: change the lower limit to something other than $x$, say $0$ and the upper limit to something other than $b$. Then it can do it.

V 13.3.1